# Escape newlines in zookeeper logs using log4j 1.2 SyslogAppender

Tags: log4j, apache-zookeeper, syslog, rsyslog

I'm running Apache Zookeeper 3.4.6, which in turn uses log4j 1.2.16. I have its logs writing to a local rsyslog server, which is all well and good. However, when exception messages are logged, the stack trace is logged as a multi-line message, which breaks my syslog message formatting. It's as if the `SyslogAppender` is sending each line as a separate syslog event, which is bizarre and probably wrong.

My log4j configuration:

```
log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.SyslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Facility=Local3
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern={myhost} zookeeper %m (%c)
```

My rsyslog template:

```
template(name="LocalFormat" type="list") {
  property(name="timestamp" dateFormat="rfc3339")
  constant(value=" ")
  property(name="hostname")
  constant(value=" ")
  property(name="syslogtag")
  constant(value=" ")
  property(name="msg" spifno1stsp="on" )
  property(name="msg" droplastlf="on" )
  constant(value="\n")
}

$ActionFileDefaultTemplate LocalFormat
```

The problematic log messages look like this:

```
2015-10-16T18:07:29.023590+00:00 {myhost} zookeeper caught end of stream exception (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
2015-10-16T18:07:29.023669+00:00 localhost EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x0, likely client has closed socket
2015-10-16T18:07:29.023763+00:00 localhost     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
2015-10-16T18:07:29.023763+00:00 localhost     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
2015-10-16T18:07:29.023763+00:00 localhost     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I was hoping to escape newlines, but [they don't seem to be an option in log4j 1.2.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html). It [definitely is in 2.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) but I'm not so sure about 1.x. Is there a way to do it *in log4j 1.2.x* even though I don't control the source code logging these messages?